# Expanding window regression using rollRegress (and not a rolling window)

Tags: r, statistics, regression, rolling-computation

I am trying to run an expanding window regression for some columns of my data. I would like to record the coefficients but would also like that my regression window has a minimum number of observations.

The package I was trying to use is rollRegress, this package seems useful as I can specify the minimum number of observations I want to use to estimate my results (I would like to use a minimum of 24 obs and then have it expand). Below was the code I was trying to run. This in theory should calculate coefficients once 24 pairs of observations exist and then return new coefficients with 25 pairs and then 26 pairs and so on until the final row of observations.

```
rolled <- roll_regres(matrix[,1] ~ matrix[,2], do_downdates = FALSE, min_obs = 24)
```

When I run this model I get the following error unfortunately,

```
Error in assert_int(width, lower = ncol(x) + 1L, upper = nrow(x)) : 
  argument "width" is missing, with no default
```

I have looked in the codes description and width appears only applicable when you want to do a rolling window but again, I am looking to use an expanding window. Does anyone have any advice?

Best

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine without your data; however, the problem seems to be due to your lack of the "width" argument. Up to now, the package directions implies that the width argument is "Only used if do_downdates ==TRUE", but it seems to be necessary. The package manager says that that issue will be corrected soon.